# Pandas: Incorrect column names are displayed in dataframe and set_index generating KeyError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am very new to data science and programming. I am working  on Movies metadata dataset from kaggle, trying to check the column names and set the index. But on opening the CSV in jupyter all the column names are displayed with a suffix'u'. Like title column is displayed as -u'title'. In the video where example is played, column names are not displayed with prefix. On trying to set the same column as index, it is generating KeyError.

I have tried with python2

```
df.columns
Index([u'adult', u'belongs_to_collection', u'budget', u'genres', u'homepage',
       u'id', u'imdb_id', u'original_language', u'original_title', u'overview',
       u'popularity', u'poster_path', u'production_companies',
       u'production_countries', u'release_date', u'revenue', u'runtime',
       u'spoken_languages', u'status', u'tagline', u'title', u'video',
       u'vote_average', u'vote_count'],
      dtype='object')

#Change the index to the title
df = df.set_index('title')

Error:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'title'
```

Comment: Presumably you used pd.read_csv to load the data. Perhaps you need to set the encoding. For example try pd.read_csv(path, encoding='utf-8')

Comment: "u" is for unicode. it is a unicode string.

Comment: Thank you for the quick replies. I tried to set encoding. But the 'u' is still displaying. Is there any other way to get it removed?

Comment: You can also use `ISO-8859-1` at the time you want to open the csv. Did you try with this too?

Comment: I am still getting the error. Am I doing something wrong?I have tried in these two ways:                                                                                                          1) df= pd.read_csv("H:\\Study data\\All Python\\Datasets\\Datasets\\themoviesdataset\\movies_metadata.csv", encoding='UTF-8') 
                                                                                                                         
2)  df= pd.read_csv('H:\\Study data\\All Python\\Datasets\\Datasets\\themoviesdataset\\movies_metadata.csv', encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')